# Why is my small SQL comment not backed up in the .swp file?

Tags: vimrc, swap-file

**Problem:**

The changes I make in files before closing are not saved in .swp files
As I understand it, the swap file should save any changes if they are at least 200 characters long or nothing has been typed for 4 seconds

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create new file tmp.sql
2. Write some text as a comment:

/* This is the comment I wrote. I did not save after I wrote it*/

3. Close window after about 10 seconds have passed
4. Restart Vim and open file using “:e”
5. I get the usual .swp message from vim
6. I type “r” to recover

**Error Message:**

```
Error: “Unable to read block 0 from /home/csarraille/docs/qua/tmp.sql

Maybe no changes were made or Vim did not update the swap file.
```

**Environment:**

- My .swp files are stored in their own folder. I specify this in my .vimrc

  :set directory=$HOME/.vim/swapfiles//
- I use Cygwin on a Windows machine to run Vim 8.0

Included Patches: 1-1567

Comment: I doubt this is it (hence comment), but the 200 characters/4 seconds are defaults and it's possible you've overridden them in .vimrc (or elsewhere). You can confirm these values with `:set updatecount` and `:set updatetime`.

Comment: Thank you @brhfl. My default settings were OK, but I appreciate knowing about  how to set them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but rather than what I had in my .vimrc for .swp file management, which was:

```
set directory=$HOME/.vim/swapfiles//
```

...The error described below has resolved by using this, placed at the very end of my .vimrc:

```
set directory=/tmp//
```

For users of Cygwin, perhaps placing the swapfile directory within the .vim directory does not work.